# pygtk image grid

Tags: python, gridview, pygtk

I'm looking for an easy way to implement something like this: http://www.dinointeractive.com/?p=117. And I was guessing if somebody here had an idea.

I want to arrange images in a grid view.
And additionally the images should arrange their position automaticly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [gtk.IconView](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkiconview.html) useful. You might also want to look into [gtk.Layout](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtklayout.html) depending on what you might want to do.

Some sample code can be found [here](http://www.learnpygtk.org/pygtktutorial/iconview.html) and a related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596926/pygtk-is-this-possible-to-draw-treeview-listed-like-iconview).