# pygtk: a row of clickable images

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I have several hboxes of images contained inside a vbox

How do I make the images clickable?
I tried containing each image inside a EventBox. If this is the right approach, how do I resize the EventBox to the the same size as its image? I tried `.set_size_request` but it does not do anything

```
self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
hboxes = []
for f in files:
   hbox = gtk.HBox()
   hbox.set_size_request(800, 150)
   for img in images:
       event_box = gtk.EventBox()
       event_box.add(img)
       event_box.connect("button_press_event", hello)
       event_box.set_size_request(250, 150)
       hbox.pack_end(event_box, padding=10, fill=False, expand=False)
       hboxes.append(hbox)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an iconview instead of the nested vboxes and hboxes. An example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3606867/217994