# Collapse empty gtk.CellRenderer

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a `gtk.TreeViewColumn` that contains 14 `gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` attributes. Most of them are empty most of the time (the assiciated `TreeStore` value is `None`).

These icons always appear spaced as though they were all present, however I would like empty cell renderers to collapse, stacking the icons which are there on the left.

This is how it currently appears:

[image]

The missing icons are associated with `None`.

I have looked through the `TreeViewColumn` and `CellRenderer` documentation but I am stumped.

Comment: So If I understand you correctly, you don't want columns in your TreeView to persist if there are holes in a row? I'm doubtful that it's going to work. (Have you concidered just placing the icons in `HBox`:s and the `HBox`:s in a `VBox`?

Comment: Also, it might be slightly more likely to get it too work as you wish with GTK3 in combination with some CSS magic (still won't believe it until I see it though).

Comment: @deinonychusaur all the icons are in the same column. One column, 14 pixbuf renderers - i'll post a pic of what I mean

Comment: I think this is exactly your question, that is -- make your own CellRenderer (the accepted answer, haven't tried it myself and some links are broken): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596926/pygtk-is-this-possible-to-draw-treeview-listed-like-iconview

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to write your own CellRenderer which accepts lists of icons. Look at the implementation of such a renderer of [Getting Things GNOME!](http://gtg.fritalk.com/) ToDO app:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gtg/gtg/trunk/view/head:/GTG/gtk/browser/CellRendererTags.py

Then you set `tag_list` attribute with a list of objects to display. (In the app you can show a solid color or an icon)

The result looks like this (list of icons is the first column):

[image]

Comment: New website: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/GTG and: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.GTG